# Mapping to different objects, depending on child collections

Tags: c#, xml, automapper

The project I'm currently working on requires me to map several (XML) objects to different objects. In order to make my life easier I decided to use AutoMapper for this purpose and it's doing a great job in facilitating the required features.

However, there is 1 mapping which I'm struggling with.

First, let me give you the XML which we are receiving from a customer:

```
<OURCOMPANY_ETA>        
    ...
    <ROUTE_ACTIONS> 
        <TRIP>1294783</TRIP>
        <SHIPMENT_NO>6483</SHIPMENT_NO>
        <ACTION_TYPE>SomeOtherAction</ACTION_TYPE >
        <ETA_DATE>2016-10-24</ETA_DATE>
        <ETA_TIME>22:22</ETA_TIME>
    </ROUTE_ACTIONS>    
    ... 
</OURCOMPANY_ETA>
```

This should get translated to an object looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>          
<OURCOMPANY_ETA>            
    ..
    <SHIPMENTS>     
        <SHIPMENT>  
            <OURCOMPANYID>6483/1294783</OURCOMPANYID>
            <ACTION_TYPE>SomeOtherAction</ACTION_TYPE>
            <EDA>2016-10-24</EDA>
            <ETA>22:22</ETA>
        </SHIPMENT> 
    </SHIPMENTS>
    ...
</OURCOMPANY_ETA>
```

You might have noticed the customer has an element called `ROUTE_ACTIONS`. This element is NOT a collection of `ROUTE_ACTION` elements as you would expect, but just a single node containing some data.
The XML we have ourselves contains a `SHIPMENTS` node with childnodes called `SHIPMENT`. These SHIPMENT nodes match nicely to the `ROUTE_ACTIONS`

The mapping of a customer object to our own object is quite feasable. We just create a new `SHIPMENTS` node with just 1 `SHIPMENT` node and everything works.
However, the problem arises when moving back from our own object to the customer's object. The customer can't handle collections, so we have to create a new object for each `SHIPMENT` node in our own object.

Given the following XML

```
...
<SHIPMENTS>     
    <SHIPMENT>  
        <OURCOMPANYID>6483/1294783</OURCOMPANYID>
        <ACTION_TYPE>SomeOtherAction</ACTION_TYPE>
        <EDA>2016-10-24</EDA>
        <ETA>22:22</ETA>
    </SHIPMENT> 
    <SHIPMENT>  
        <OURCOMPANYID>3123/47348236</OURCOMPANYID>
        <ACTION_TYPE>SomeAction</ACTION_TYPE>
        <EDA>2016-10-24</EDA>
        <ETA>22:22</ETA>
    </SHIPMENT> 
</SHIPMENTS>
...
```

We will have to create 2 objects, similar to this:

```
<OURCOMPANY_ETA>        
    ...
    <ROUTE_ACTIONS> 
        <TRIP>1294783</TRIP>
        <SHIPMENT_NO>6483</SHIPMENT_NO>
        <ACTION_TYPE>SomeOtherAction</ACTION_TYPE >
        <ETA_DATE>2016-10-24</ETA_DATE>
        <ETA_TIME>22:22</ETA_TIME>
    </ROUTE_ACTIONS>    
    ...
</OURCOMPANY_ETA>       
<!--And another object-->
<OURCOMPANY_ETA>        
    ...
    <ROUTE_ACTIONS> 
        <TRIP>47348236</TRIP>
        <SHIPMENT_NO>3123</SHIPMENT_NO>
        <ACTION_TYPE>SomeAction</ACTION_TYPE >
        <ETA_DATE>2016-10-24</ETA_DATE>
        <ETA_TIME>22:22</ETA_TIME>
    </ROUTE_ACTIONS>
    ...
</OURCOMPANY_ETA>
```

Any ideas on how to handle this using AutoMapper? If it's not possible to do this directly, is it possible to create my own logic and still use AutoMapping to call this logic, like with an `IValueResolver`?

I've used the Visual Studio Paste XML to Objects to generate the objects. For completeness, they are found at the end of this post. Didn't add them at first as they are quite big.

The mapping I've created so far is the following:

```
CreateMap<Convertor.Customer.Model.Eta.OURCOMPANY_ETA, Convertor.Model.OURCOMPANY.Eta.OURCOMPANY_ETA>()
        .ForMember(ed => ed.TIMESTAMP, opt => opt.MapFrom(es => es.DATETIME_CREATED))
        .ForMember(ed => ed.SHIPMENTS, opt => opt.MapFrom(es => es.ROUTE_ACTIONS))
        .ForMember(ed => ed.SUBCONTRACTOR_CODE, opt => opt.Ignore())
        .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.VERSION = new decimal(2.0)); 
    CreateMap<Convertor.Model.OURCOMPANY.Eta.OURCOMPANY_ETA, Convertor.Customer.Model.Eta.OURCOMPANY_ETA>()
        .ForMember(ed => ed.DATETIME_CREATED, opt => opt.MapFrom(es => es.TIMESTAMP))
        .ForMember(ed => ed.ROUTE_ACTIONS, opt => opt.MapFrom(es => es.SHIPMENTS))
        .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.VERSION = new decimal(1.3));

CreateMap<Convertor.Customer.Model.Eta.OURCOMPANY_ETAROUTE_ACTIONS, Convertor.Model.OURCOMPANY.Eta.OURCOMPANY_ETASHIPMENT>()
        .ForMember(ed => ed.OURCOMPANYID, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<EtaValueResolvers.GenerateOURCOMPANYId>());

    CreateMap<Convertor.Model.OURCOMPANY.Eta.OURCOMPANY_ETASHIPMENT, Convertor.Customer.Model.Eta.OURCOMPANY_ETAROUTE_ACTIONS>()
        .ForMember(ed => ed.SHIPMENT_NO, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<EtaValueResolvers.ExtractShipmentOURCOMPANYId>())
        .ForMember(ed => ed.TRIP, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<EtaValueResolvers.ExtractTripOURCOMPANYId>());
```

Our company it's object is looking like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class OURCOMPANY_ETA
{

    private System.DateTime tIMESTAMPField;

    private string sUBCONTRACTOR_NAMEField;

    private string sUBCONTRACTOR_CODEField;

    private string OURCOMPANYCOMPANYField;

    private decimal vERSIONField;

    private OURCOMPANY_ETASHIPMENT[] sHIPMENTSField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime TIMESTAMP
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tIMESTAMPField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tIMESTAMPField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string SUBCONTRACTOR_NAME
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sUBCONTRACTOR_NAMEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sUBCONTRACTOR_NAMEField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string SUBCONTRACTOR_CODE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sUBCONTRACTOR_CODEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sUBCONTRACTOR_CODEField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OURCOMPANYCOMPANY
    {
        get
        {
            return this.OURCOMPANYCOMPANYField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OURCOMPANYCOMPANYField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal VERSION
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vERSIONField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vERSIONField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("SHIPMENT", IsNullable = false)]
    public OURCOMPANY_ETASHIPMENT[] SHIPMENTS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sHIPMENTSField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sHIPMENTSField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class OURCOMPANY_ETASHIPMENT
{

    private string OURCOMPANYIDField;

    private string aCTION_TYPEField;

    private System.DateTime eDAField;

    private string eTAField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OURCOMPANYID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.OURCOMPANYIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OURCOMPANYIDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ACTION_TYPE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.aCTION_TYPEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.aCTION_TYPEField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime EDA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eDAField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eDAField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ETA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eTAField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eTAField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The customer it's object is looking like this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class OURCOMPANY_ETA
{

    private System.DateTime dATETIME_CREATEDField;

    private string cHARTERCODEField;

    private string OURCOMPANY_COMPANYField;

    private decimal vERSIONField;

    private OURCOMPANY_ETAROUTE_ACTIONS rOUTE_ACTIONSField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public System.DateTime DATETIME_CREATED
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dATETIME_CREATEDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dATETIME_CREATEDField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string CHARTERCODE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cHARTERCODEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cHARTERCODEField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string OURCOMPANY_COMPANY
    {
        get
        {
            return this.OURCOMPANY_COMPANYField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.OURCOMPANY_COMPANYField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal VERSION
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vERSIONField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vERSIONField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public OURCOMPANY_ETAROUTE_ACTIONS ROUTE_ACTIONS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rOUTE_ACTIONSField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.rOUTE_ACTIONSField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class OURCOMPANY_ETAROUTE_ACTIONS
{

    private string tRIPField;

    private string sHIPMENT_NOField;

    private string aCTION_TYPEField;

    private System.DateTime eTA_DATEField;

    private string eTA_TIMEField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string TRIP
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tRIPField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tRIPField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string SHIPMENT_NO
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sHIPMENT_NOField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sHIPMENT_NOField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ACTION_TYPE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.aCTION_TYPEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.aCTION_TYPEField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")]
    public System.DateTime ETA_DATE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eTA_DATEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eTA_DATEField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ETA_TIME
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eTA_TIMEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eTA_TIMEField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you converting XML to XML or objects to objects? If XML to XML, then XSLT is a much better option than AutoMapper. If object to object, please post your class definitions, not the XML structures

Comment: so you don't have `root` element in result xml?

Comment: Please post some C# code where you query the data and call AutoMapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of sharing my knowledge on this problem, here's what I've come up with so far and it appears to be working. I won't mark it as the definitive answer just yet, because someone might come up with a better, more elegant, solution.

What I did is ending up using an `ITypeConverter` in which one has ultimate control of the objects. However, the solution has nothing to do with AutoMapper anymore, aside of still using the library for mapping.

```
public class OurCompanyEtaToCustomerObjectsConvertor : ITypeConverter<Convertor.Model.OurCompany.Eta.OurCompany_ETA, Eta.OurCompany_ETA[]>
{
    public Customer.Model.Eta.OurCompany_ETA[] Convert(Convertor.Model.OurCompany.Eta.OurCompany_ETA source, Customer.Model.Eta.OurCompany_ETA[] destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        destination = new Eta.OurCompany_ETA[0];
        if (source != null)
        {
            if (source.SHIPMENTS != null)
            {
                foreach (var OurCompanyEtashipment in source.SHIPMENTS)
                {
                    var CustomerModel = new Customer.Model.Eta.OurCompany_ETA();
                    //Other stuff....
                    destination = destination.Concat(new[] {CustomerModel}).ToArray();
                }
            }                       
        }
        return destination;
    }
}
```

And the map looks like this:

```
CreateMap<Convertor.Model.OurCompany.Eta.OurCompany_ETA, Convertor.Customer.Model.Eta.OurCompany_ETA[]>()
            .ConvertUsing(new EtaValueResolvers.OurCompanyEtaToCustomerObjectsConvertor());
```

You might notice I also had to change the Destination model to an array in order to use the type converter.
It's probably not a very elegant solution, but I couldn't think of something else and still use AutoMapper.

The main reason to keep using AutoMapper is because it's doing a great job for our other 50+ objects. This is the only object for which we struggled and I didn't want to change our generic codebase, just for this single anomaly.